# jersey deployment

Tags: java, deployment, jersey

I have developed a Jersey Resource class.

Can someone please tell me how can I deploy it on a Web App server. Preferably Tomcat or JBoss.

Or a better question still, can Jersey applications with only a resource class be deployed on a Web App server? If yes, How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by using web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.resources;org.bar.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

or in Java (without a servlet container):

```
public class MyConfig extends PackagesResourceConfig {

   public MyApplication() {
      super("com.foo.resources;org.bar.resources");
   }
}
```

or subclassing Application:

```
public class MyApplicaton extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(com.foo.resources.MyResource.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: so i just create a web app in any ide. put the above changes in web.xml, put my resource class in the source forlder of the new webapp and it will be ready to go.. Is it really that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying in a servlet container will certainly work if you need the servlet container.  Simpler and recommended by Jersey is with Grizzly - http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e60

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load your jesey engine to your web application, that can be done by using web.xml, and set loadonstartup as 1.

you can read the first jersery application and configurations [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)

you can see the simple hello world example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/)